# Why This Class <Not Responding>

Tags: objective-c, class

Hi
i dont know why i call a function in "msg" class
it has no respond:(

this is the "msg" class:

msg.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface msg : NSObject {

}

-(void) Print;

@end
```

msg.m :

```
#import "msg.h"


@implementation msg

-(void) Print {
 NSLog(@"Hello World");
}

@end
```

viewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "msg.h"

@class msg;
@interface ClassMod4ViewController : UIViewController {

 msg *object;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) msg *object;

@end
```

viewController.m :

```
#import "ClassMod4ViewController.h"

@implementation ClassMod4ViewController
@synthesize object;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

 [object Print];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This code looks perfectly fine. Can you provide the exact error message?

Comment: it has no message in Run Console "NSLog"!!??

Comment: Given that you lower cased the class name, capitalized the method name and have asked several questions below that indicate a lack of knowledge of Objective-C, I'd suggest you start here:http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the object initialized in the designated initializer (usually `initWithNibName:bundle:` for UIViewController subclasses) prior to viewDidLoad being invoked?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    // ...
    object = [[Msg alloc] init];
    // ...
    return self;
}
```

If the object has not been initialized, then it's nil.  Remember that it's okay to send nil objects messages in Objective-C (nothing will happen as a result).

Comment: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'object' Error

Comment: I elaborated my answer a bit to indicate where to initialize object at.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 assert(object);    
 [object Print];
 [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

?

if the assertion fails, then the pointer to `object` is 0 (or `nil`). you must create the object before you use it. this is *typically* performed in the initializer (in your case, of the class that contains the instance of `object`):

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (0 != self) {
        object = [[msg alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

but sometimes you'll want to create the object later on.

if you are initializing it, then you may want to set breakpoints where the object is accessed in order to determine where the object is set to 0.

Comment: Assertion failed: (object) Error

Comment: thanks but can you show me the way of writing a Class in obj-c?

Comment: sorry, no. it's a big subject, considering the time i have available. fortunately, the way of writing a class in objc has been already covered in many forms as objc is a popular language - just read some docs, books, and SO posts. cheers.